# How to have ZipFile only zip a specified directory - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, zip

When I try to zip a directory with the following code, my directory is zipped and contains all the files I would like zipped, however it is also zipping the root directories for the directory I would like zipped.

(Test is the target directory to be zipped - it contains other directories and files) When unzipping the my_python_files.zip, it unzips with absolute paths:

unzipping my_python_files.zip:

\Users\hhafez\Desktop\Test

when I would like to have:

\Test

I am having trouble trying to find a way to avoid this, any tips would be much appreciated.

```
def get_all_file_paths(directory):
    file_paths = []

    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)

    return file_paths

def zipfiles():    
    file_paths = get_all_file_paths(r"C:\Users\hhafez\Desktop\Test") 
    with ZipFile('my_python_files.zip','w') as myzip: 
        for file in file_paths:
            print(file)
            myzip.write(file) 

    print('All files zipped successfully!')         

zipfiles()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to zip the list of files and dont want the zip archive to contain the absolute paths of each file...

```
def zipFiles(directory):
    parentDir = "C:\Users\hhafez\Desktop"  #hardcoding parent path to strip
    with ZipFile('my_python_files.zip','w') as myzip: 
        for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
            zipFileName = root[len(parentDir):] #always take whats after the parentDir for the filename going in the zip
            for file in files:
                myzip.write(os.path.join(root,file), os.path.join(zipFileName,file), compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) 


zipfiles(r"C:\Users\hhafez\Desktop\Test")
```

This should accomplish what you need. The major difference here is the zipFileName variable.

```
 zipFileName = root[len(parentDir):]
```

This line strips out the parentDir from the directory that you are crawling through . zipFileName and the name of the file would be the archive name to pass to myzip.write which explains this:

```
myzip.write(os.path.join(root,file), os.path.join(zipFileName,file), compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Comment: basename seems to get rid of all the directories within my target directory, I would like to leave everything intact within the target directory.

Comment: @HishamHafez removed my basename attempt and changed my solution according to your comment